# Simplifying a log of a log

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I have a summation series that unfortunately involves a log of a log. It looks like the following (assume all $\log$ are log base $2$):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \log\log\frac{n}{2^{k-i}}
$$

I'd like to simplify this somehow, such as move the logs or the n value to the outside of the equation, so that I can use the closed form of the geometric series sum to further simplify the equation, but I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a small guide on how to make your math look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's see:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \log(\log(n\cdot 2^{-i}))  = \log\left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\log n + \log 2^{-i}\right) = \log\left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \log n - i\right) = \log\Big(k! \binom{\log n}k\Big) = \log((\log n)_k) = \log\Big(\frac{\Gamma(\log n +1)}{\Gamma(\log n - k + 1)}\Big)=\color{maroon}{\log(\Gamma(\log n + 1)) - \log(\Gamma(\log n - k + 1))}$$
Where $(x)_k$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol)
$$(x)_k = x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)$$
We used $\log a + \log b = \log(ab)$ and $\log_2 2^k = k$.

Comment: I don't know if that helps in any way, but $\log\left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \log n - i\right) = \log \left( (\log n)^{\underline{k}}\right)$, where $a^{\underline k}$ denotes the falling factorial.

Comment: @hife Good suggestion.

Comment: @AlexR You should say what that notation means in the answer.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Well, it seems obvious but okay.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, all. This sort of simplification is fairly foreign to me, so could you lend some insight into the Pochhammer symbol? I'm trying to come up with the simplest closed form possible for this series. For further reference, I will be substituting log(n) for k once I have a closed form of the summation. is @hife right with k as an exponent in the final portion, or is AlexR right with the Pochhammer symbol? Thanks again.

Comment: @drshmoo Well, it's just a compact notation of the product. You can pick some formula for it from the wiki page. For example
$$(x)_n = \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x-n+1)}$$

Comment: The Pochhammer symbol is just a notation for the falling factorial. They are the same thing (see the link in AlexR's answer).

Comment: @drshmoo Actually using this formula, you can arrive at a fairly nice "closed form" assuming you permit the $\Gamma$ function (wich has no closed form in elementary functions, but quickly converging series for numerical evaluation)

Comment: @drshmoo: If you wish to substitute log(n) for k, you have to be careful, as the calculations made assumed k to be a positive integer. You would then have to take the integer part of log(n).

Comment: By the way, I've never seen an actual _proof_ that Gamma can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions...

Comment: @columbus8myhw Neither have I but my professor assured me of this some years ago, proof by authority!

Comment: For some more background, this product series results from the recurrence relation T(n) = 4T(n/2) + 5(n^2)*lg(lg(n)). Backwards substitution produces the series. Is all of the above still true if the 2^(k-1) produces a geometric series (2, 4, 8, 16, etc)? I'm guessing that since the lg(lg(...) is present, we aren't able to apply the closed form for a typical geometric series.

Comment: @drshmoo I don't quite understand what you mean by "if [it] produces a geometric series". It doesn't, really. If you're interested in $\lim_{k\to\infty}$ you should ask a follow-up question.

Comment: I suppose I've been led to expect certain behavior from my course. To confirm: n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16...+ n/2^(k-1) is not a geometric series in the context of this problem?

Comment: @drshmoo You're summing $\log\log x$, not $x$. The inner part would be a geometric sum _if_ it were summed on its own.